# How to save pictures in a safe storage and access them in android?

Tags: android, image, url, storage

In my application,I want to download images from an `URL` and then save them in a safe area in `Android` device. But I have no idea about storage options in `Android`. I don't want to use `sdcard` or another external storages.

Comment: As suggested use internal storage, but since that is limited on some devices, why don't you want to use the SDCard? If it is for privacy reasons - you could encrypt the data before saving it to the SDCard

Comment: I think, i will use galaxy tab. Can you give me detailes about that devices internal storage...

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not a good practice to save your application data in the limited internal storage of the device you can do that.

Check the official google documentation for saving data in the internal device storage which will give you lead about storing stuff in the internal.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: I will download the images from an url and in my application. But i want to save them and then use. Because i don' t want to download them again and again. Can you tell me the best way. I have also read about content providers. Do they work or they are not relevant?

Comment: You need to do lazy loading of the images.In your case you need to download them and store them in your application's private local storage for later use.It's more like a cache mechanism for your pictures.The best way to do that is using an AsyncTask to download the images in the background and saving it for later use.You can create your own mechanism or check some sample to get some lead about Lazy Loading in your ListView from here https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: how can i store the pictures in my application's private local storage. "The best way to do that is using an AsyncTask to download the images in the background and saving it for later use" How can i save them or where can i save them.

Comment: Well actually there's no automated way to do that you need to do it manually and implement your own logic and algorithms for getting the data and saving it in a file or folder.For your case better create a folder for your application in the internal storage and store the images there.

Answer (score 0):

You can then convert you image > Bitmap > ToBytes and then into Base64 String object. By this you will get a String representation of your Image and you can simply store that into SQLlite DB.

*Warnig : This may lose image quality.*

TO convert drawable into Base64 String.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
imgString = Base64.encodeBytes(b);
```

To convert String back to drawable. Get String from SQLite DB and then

```
byte[] b = Base64.decode(imgString);
Bitmap bc = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
Drawlable drawabe = new BitmapDrawable(bc).getCurrent();
```

Comment: I don't want to use sd card. I want to use internal storage that is only accesible by the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

use iternal storage http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal and force app to instal in internal http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install

on non rooted devices should be enough ...

Comment: Can you explain me the differences between storing and caching?

Comment: cache use different function to file access, should be limited to about 1MB for app and can be deleted when system need more space ... storage acts as normal file system but is stored in protected place where only your app can access

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this could be useful for you (as it was for me): https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: @Arslan: yes indeed. This is the best way to solve this problem and Fedor implemented a good solution.

Comment: Please read question carefully. Question is about to DOT save image on SDCard

Comment: Ok ok. I would explain me better and maybe ask the guy for this special choice. My suggestion were to use external storage instead of other methods because internal memory is often overloading and this could lead to major issues.